# Invalid salt revision when comparing Python generated hash with raw password in Java

Tags: java, python, bcrypt, jbcrypt

So I've created a database which stores user information and their hashed password, which is hashed using a **Python** script using the `bcrypt` module.

Now to login using my Java client, I am using the `JBCrypt` library included as a Maven dependency in my IntelliJ project. It retrieves the hash and the database connection works perfectly, the only issue is that it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid salt revision
    at org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.hashpw(BCrypt.java:671)
    at org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.checkpw(BCrypt.java:763)
    at mypackage.Login.validateUser(Login.java:81)
    at mypackage.Login.actionPerformed(Login.java:63)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:269)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6578)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3343)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6343)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2259)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4961)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2317)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4793)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4539)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4480)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2303)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2758)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4793)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:711)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:99)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:199)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

The code for checking is as follows:

```
String dbHash = results.getString("password");
System.out.println(dbHash);
boolean result = BCrypt.checkpw(new String(passwordField.getPassword()), dbHash);
```

**EDIT:** An **example** of the hashed password and raw password from the Python module script is as follows:

```
Raw:    zO/15;w|c'*uftH)
Hashed: $2b$12$7Y4ZmORuoH0dziYSg8dpd.PfvWQx2QPcoiRoGWg.HKfhuN6evEZnO
```

**EDIT: ** I have noticed it is because JBCrypt does not seem to support anything greater than `$2a` hashes. I cannot find the `bcrypt` module documentation for Python so I cannot determine if I can use a `$2a` hash in the Python code.

Comment: Please post an example of a hashed + actual password.

Comment: @lexicore updated OP

Comment: Yes, seems like incompatible version. `$2a$...` would go.

Comment: @lexicore Are you saying that `JBCrypt` requires `$2a$...` salt? Maybe there's a way in the Python module to use this

Comment: I'm saying that `$2b$` is apparently not supported. It seems like these prefixes denote a version of hash. And from the quick googling looks like `$2a$` [was vulnerable](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20541/insecure-versions-of-crypt-hashes). Maybe jbcrypt was not updated yet? Last release is from 2015.

Comment: Yeah that might be the issue, according to the `bcrypt` Python module v3.1.0 they `Fixed a regression where $2a hashes were vulnerable to a wraparound bug.` -- So there must be a way to use the `$2a` hash

Comment: Yes, but that's on the Python side.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was an issue with `JBCrypt`. It is outdated (it can verify only `$2a` hashes.

Therefore to fix this, I had to change the Python script to generate a salt which uses a `$2a` prefix:

> Adjustable Prefix
>
> Another one of bcrypt’s features is an adjustable
>   prefix to let you define what libraries you’ll remain compatible with.
>   To adjust this, pass either 2a or 2b (the default) to
>   bcrypt.gensalt(prefix=b"2b") as a bytes object.
>
> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/3.1.0

Answer (score 2):

From the source code, it seems the exception is coming from [checking the format of the hashed password](https://github.com/jeremyh/jBCrypt/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mindrot/BCrypt.java#L659-L668):

```
    if (salt.charAt(0) != '$' || salt.charAt(1) != '2')
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Invalid salt version");
    if (salt.charAt(2) == '$')
        off = 3;
    else {
        minor = salt.charAt(2);
        if (minor != 'a' || salt.charAt(3) != '$')
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Invalid salt revision");
        off = 4;
    }
```

So my guess would be that `dbHash` for some reason does not match the format. Either it is generated by an incompatible version. Or it is actually not hashed. Or empty.

Comment: I've printed the hash and checked it using generators online. So it must be an incompatible password

Comment: @madcrazydrumma Any chance that you actually post and example of a password + hashed password?